# How to divide two 32 bit numbers in Inline assembly in c

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

My code is below. I want to divide val2/val1 and store it to result variable.

```
int func(int val1=12, int val2=234234) {
    int  result;
    _asm
    {
        mov eax, val1;
        mov ebx, val2;
        xor edx, edx         
        idiv  eax;
        mov result,eax;
    }



    return result;

}
```

I have tried div,idiv. However I get always 0 or 234234.Also I tried `mov result abx` but it is same again.

Could you explain why it is so?

Comment: You want `idiv  ebx`. Given the operands, you likely have `val1` and `val2` swapped as well.

Comment: Recall that `idiv` divides the contents of `edx:eax` by the operand.  So you dividing by `eax` is very suspicious.  Have you tried `mov eax val2; cdq; idiv val1; mov result, eax`?

Comment: @fuz, it worked,can you explain what was logic behind?

Comment: @ElvinJafarov Well I just used the `idiv` instruction as it is specified in the manual.  Refer to the Intel Software Development Manuals for how it is used.  The `cdq` instruction before is important, too.  It sign-extends `eax` into `edx:eax` as `idiv` expects.